# How to return the correct response to the client in microservice architecture?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, microservices, azureservicebus

The client will send a request to s1 and for s1 to respond it needs to get data from s2.

Question: How s1 will read the correct response coming from s2 ?
as with the current design s1 might read the response of client2 and return it to client1

[image]

**Logical diagram**

[image]

Comment: something like a unique request-id should be a part of the initial request so that it can be tracked independently

Answer (score 0):

Typically a correlation id is generated as soon as the request is received. This correlation id is then passed to all the distributed systems to enable coordination, tracing and logging throughout the whole request process.

In this case s1 would probably generate the correlation id, and it would include this id along with all the other relevant data in the message that it publishes the service bus. When s2 does it's work it then includes the id in the response it pushes back.

The process within s1 that generated the id listens for *all* the messages from s2, but only reacts to the message that contains the right id, returning the data to the original client.

Try https://www.google.com/search?q=use+of+correlation+id+in+distributed+applications for more background